# How can I dynamically extend/modify all methods of inherited class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a class like this:

```
class MainClass
  def self.method_one(String)
      puts "#{self.class} a"
  end
  def self.method_two(String)
      puts "#{self.class} a"
  end
end
```

And I have a class which inherits the `MainClass`:

```
class NewClass < MainClass
  #any_mathod should match any method that is called for NewClass call
  def self.any_method(a,b)
     puts "#{self.class} b"
     super(a)
  end
end
```

Is there any way how can I extend all methods from the `MainClass` when running them from `NewClass` without redefining them all in `NewClass` to accept two parameters instead of one, for example:

```
NewClass.method_one(String1, String2)
```

And it will produce:

```
#=> NewClass String2
#=> MainClass String1
```

and to process `String1` parameter within `NewClass` class. The processor for the additional parameter will be the same for all the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MainClass
    def self.method_one(string)
        puts string
    end
    def self.method_two(string)
        puts string
    end
end


class NewClass < MainClass
    #Iterate through all methods specific to MainClass and redefine
    (self.superclass.public_methods - Object.public_methods).each do |method|
        define_singleton_method method do |string1, string2|
            #Common processing for String1
            puts string1 

            #Call the MainClass method to process String2
            super(string2)
        end
    end
end
```

NewClass will iterate through all methods defined specifically in MainClass. Then it will define a class method for NewClass that processes String1 and then calls the MainClass method to process String2.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wanted `super` method

```
class A
  def self.method_one(a)
    puts "a is #{a}"
  end
end

class B < A
  (superclass.methods - superclass.superclass.methods).each do |m|
    define_singleton_method(m) do |a, b|
      puts "b is #{b}"
      super(a)
    end
  end
end

B.method_one(5, 10)

# => b is 10
# => a is 5
```

Comment: Yeah, but is it possible to do it somehow without defining method_one method in "B" class?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to ditch inheritance and use modules instead:

```
module TestModule
  def awesome1
  end
  def awesome2
  end
end

class TestClass
  def self.include mod
    puts (mod.instance_methods - Module.methods).sort
    super
  end
  include TestModule
end
```

Add singleton methods in the overridden #include as in the above answers.